# Colour specific date of bootstraps date picker

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to colour a specific date in [bootstrap date picker](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) - In particular, the default date. So that the user may know where they are in relation to the default date.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [tour].  After doing that, please edit your question and include a [mcve] of what you are trying to accomplish so that we can provided a quicker, better answer to your specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using this example: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Your question is a bit vague so I'm asuming you are using the inline version.
Then you can use this css code to change the default color:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.active, .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.active:hover{
background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```